# How to minimize a quadratic form with constraint that sum of elements of vector is one?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

## Problem Statement

I've been trying to solve the following optimization problem

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min \limits_{\boldsymbol{w}} & \boldsymbol{w}^\top\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{w}  \\
\mbox{s.t.} & \sum_{j=1}^K w_j = 1\\
\end{array}
$$
Where $\boldsymbol{w}\in \mathbb{R}^K$ and $\boldsymbol{C}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$ and $\boldsymbol{C}$ is **symmetric**, that is $\boldsymbol{C} = \boldsymbol{C}^\top$.

## My Tentative Solution

Introduce lagrange multiplier $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and construct the Lagrangian using the vector $\boldsymbol{1}=(1, \ldots, 1)^\top \in\mathbb{R}^K$
$$
\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{w}, \lambda) = \boldsymbol{w}^\top\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{w}  - \lambda(\boldsymbol{1}^\top \boldsymbol{w} - 1)
$$
Then take the derivative with respect to $\boldsymbol{w}$

$$
\nabla_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{w}, \lambda) = 2\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{w} - \lambda\boldsymbol{1}
$$
However I am not sure how to solve this now..

Comment: Don't you mean $w^TCw$ ?

Comment: Yep! That was a typo

Comment: $w^tCw$ is minimized when $w$ is an eigenvector for the smallest eigenvalue of $C$. Then normalize to make $\sum w_i=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! Do you mind writing a full answer with a bit more detail?

Comment: The posted answers are way too complicated. You have $2Cw-\lambda1=0$ and $1^Tw=1$. This is enough equations to determine the solution: solve $\begin{bmatrix}2C&-1\\1^T&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w\\\lambda\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: In a similar vein to the comment by @Rahul, the constrained extrema occur where the hyperplane $\mathbf 1^Tw=1$ is tangent to the quadric $w^TCw=k$ (for some $k$). Depending on the rank of $C$, you can use a simple pole-polar relationship to find $k$ and then $w$ where the extremum occurs.

Comment: Do you want $w \geq 0$ as well (as it would have to be for a probability distribution or a portfolio without shorts), or is $w$ not restricted in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Construct the $w$ vector from an unconstrained vector $x$ as
$$w = \frac{x}{{\tt1}^Tx}$$
then the objective function becomes
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= w^TCw = \frac{x^TCx}{x^T{\tt11}^Tx} = \frac{x^TCx}{x^TBx} \\
}$$ where $B$ is the all-ones matrix and the function is seen to be a generalized Rayleigh quotient.

For convenience define the scalars
$$\eqalign{
\gamma &= x^TCx\quad\implies \frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x} = 2Cx \\
\beta &= x^TBx\quad\implies \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x} = 2Bx \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \beta^{-1}\gamma \\
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x}
 &= \beta^{-1}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x}
  - \gamma\beta^{-2}\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x} \\
 &= \beta^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x}
  - \lambda\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}\right) \\
 &= 2\beta^{-1}\big(Cx - \lambda Bx\big) \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields the generalized eigenvalue equation 
$$Cx = \lambda Bx$$
If any such eigenvalues exist, then the minimum eigenvalue is the minimum of the objective, and the associated eigenvector is the unconstrained solution vector $x$, from which the $w$ solution is recovered as $w = \left(\frac{x}{{\tt1}^Tx}\right)$

**NB:** The all-ones matrix is singular so $B^{-1}$ does not exist, but if $C^{-1}$ exists then this can be used to convert the equation into a standard eigenvalue equation
$$\eqalign{
A = C^{-1}B,\; \alpha=\lambda^{-1} \quad\implies Ax = \alpha x \\
}$$
which is easier to solve. Indeed, unlike the generalized equation, solutions of the standard equation are guaranteed to exist. In this case, the maximal $\alpha$ eigenvalue corresponds to the minimal $\lambda$ eigenvalue.

If the constraint were changed to $\,b^Tw=1\,$ for a given vector $b$, then the above analysis holds with the following modifications
$$B=bb^T,\quad w=\frac{x}{b^Tx}$$
Finally, even if the matrix $C$ were not symmetric, it can be *decomposed* as the sum of a symmetric and anti-symmetric matrix
$\big(C=C_s+C_a\big),\,$ 
where the anti-symmetric matrix contributes nothing to the objective, since $\,x^TC_ax\,$ is zero. So the above analysis holds after substituting $C_s$ for $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis for ${\bf R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors for $C$ (note – I've changed the dimension from $K$ to $n$). Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ be the corresponding eigenvalues. We may assume $\lambda_1\le\cdots\le\lambda_n$.

Any $w$ in ${\bf R}^n$ can be written as $w=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$ for some reals $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Then $w^tCw=\lambda_1a_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_na_n^2\ge\lambda_1(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)$  so for a fixed value of $\|w\|$, $w^tCw$ is minimized by taking $w$ to be the appropriate multiple of $v_1$.

I now see this isn't quite what was asked for, since the problem is to fix $\sum w_i$ and not $\sum w_i^2$, but it does in any event give the general form of $w^tCw$ which should be important in any approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is to point out **there is no particular reason for a minimum to exist**

The argument splits into 3 parts.  The first addresses the case where $C$ has at least one negative eigenvalue.  The second addresses the nice case where $C$ is positive definite.  The final part addresses the case where $C$ is merely positive semi-definite.

**1.)**

Consider the centering projector
$S := I - \frac{1}{\mathbf 1^T \mathbf 1}\mathbf 1\mathbf 1^T$
*lemma:*
$\big(SCS\big) \not\succeq \mathbf 0\longrightarrow \text{  there is no minimum}$

*proof:*
via Gramm Schmidt, decompose any $\mathbf w$, into $\mathbf w = \alpha\mathbf 1 + \beta \mathbf v$ where $\alpha = \frac{1}{K}$ and  $\mathbf v\perp  \mathbf 1$ and $\mathbf v$ has unit length (2 norm).

To repeat the main idea: if $\big(SCS\big)$ has negative eigenvalues then this creates a problem.

As an aside this can also be interpreted in terms of Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing.  That is the criteria implies that $C$ is problematic if it has more than one negative eigenvalue (i.e. $C$'s signature must indicate that it has at least K-1 eigenvalues that are non-negative).  The following analysis also implies $C$ is problematic if the eigenvector associated with the sole negative eigenvalues is orthogonal to $\mathbf 1$.  This result *further implies*  that for non-problematic $C$ with just one negative eigenvalue, we get the minimal value with $\mathbf w:= \text{eigenvector associated with negative eigenvalue}$ and rescale as such that $\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w = 1$.

returning to the main argument:

$f\big(\mathbf w\big) = \mathbf w^T C \mathbf w =  \beta^2 \cdot \mathbf v^T C \mathbf v +  \beta \cdot \alpha\cdot\text{trace}\Big(C\big(\mathbf {1v}^T + \mathbf {v1}^T \big)\Big)+ \alpha^2 \cdot \mathbf 1^T C \mathbf 1 $

The main point is, for any fixed choice of $\mathbf v$ the above reads
$f\big(\mathbf w\big) =   \beta^2 \cdot  \mathbf v^T C \mathbf v  +  \beta \cdot \text{constant}+ \text{constant}$

If $\big(SCS\big) \not\succeq \mathbf 0$ this should be interpreted as having made a wise choice of $\mathbf v$ and
$\mathbf v^T \big(SCS\big) \mathbf v =\mathbf v^T C \mathbf v  \lt 0$
Thus for any $r\gt 0$ we have $f\big(\mathbf w\big) \lt -r$,  for large enough $\beta$, which proves no minimum exists when $\big(SCS\big) \not\succeq \mathbf 0$.

This argument is analogous to why the image of a single variable real polynomial of degree 2 looks like 'an upside down cup' when the leading coefficient is negative. Such a polynomial doesn't have a global minimum and neither does OP's problem.

**2.)**  At the other extreme: if $C \succ \mathbf 0$ then there is a particularly simple solution.
$1 = 1^2 = \Big(\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w\Big)^2 = \Big(\big(\mathbf 1^T C^\frac{-1}{2}\big)\big(C^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf w\big)\Big)^2 = \Big(\big( C^\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf 1\big)^T \big(C^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf w\big)\Big)^2\leq \big(\mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1\big)\big(\mathbf w^T C \mathbf w\big)$
or
$\frac{1}{\mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1} \leq  \big(\mathbf w^T C \mathbf w\big)$
by Cauchy-Schwarz, with equality *iff*
$C^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf w = \gamma \cdot C^\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf 1$
or
$\mathbf w = \gamma \cdot C^{-1}\mathbf 1$
and of course we set $\mathbf w$ equal to this and select $\gamma$ by the boundary condition that $\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w = 1$, i.e. this implies
$1 = \mathbf 1^T \mathbf w = \gamma \cdot \mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1 \longrightarrow \gamma := \frac{1}{\mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1}$

**3.)** In the case of singular $C \succeq \mathbf 0$
while the solution will not in general be unique, it is straightforward to construct a solution that achieves the global minimum.

first orthogonally diagonalize
$C =  Q \Lambda  Q^T = \sum_{i=1}^K \lambda_i \mathbf q_i\mathbf q_i^T$
and using the fact that C's eigenvectors form a basis write 
$\mathbf 1 = \sum_{i=1}^K x_i \mathbf q_i$

This splits into two cases:
*(i)*
$x_i \neq 0$  for some eigenpair $(\lambda_i =0, \mathbf q_i)$
in other words $\mathbf 1$ is a linear combination of vectors and at least one of these has nonzero weight *and* is in the kernel of $C$.
*solution*
set $\mathbf w  := \gamma \mathbf q_i$ where $\gamma$ is chosen such that $\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w = 1$

This gives the minimum possible quadratic form payoff of $\mathbf w^T C \mathbf w = 0$ and satisfies $\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w = 1$

*(ii)*
$\mathbf 1$ is written as a linear combination of $C$'s eigenvectors all of which are (only) in the image of $C$ (equivalently: none of which are in the kernel of $C$).

*solution:*
observing that any component of $\mathbf w$ that is in the kernel of $\mathbf C$ neither effects the quadratic form nor the weight constraint, we can restrict ourself to only those vectors in the image of C

**abusing notation**
$C^{-1}:= Q \Lambda^{+}  Q^T$
where $\Lambda^{+}$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\frac{1}{\lambda_i}$ if $\lambda_i \neq 0$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Now re-run the Cauchy-Schwarz argument in **2.)** 
$1 = 1^2 = \Big(\mathbf 1^T \mathbf w\Big)^2 = \Big(\big(\mathbf 1^T C^\frac{-1}{2}\big)\big(C^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf w\big)\Big)^2 = \Big(\big( C^\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf 1\big)^T \big(C^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf w\big)\Big)^2\leq \big(\mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1\big)\big(\mathbf w^T C \mathbf w\big)$

to be sure, notice
$P:=C^\frac{-1}{2}C^\frac{1}{2} \neq I$  where $P^2 = P$
but $\mathbf 1^T P = \mathbf 1^T$ so the above result holds

and again the minimum is achieved when
$\mathbf w = \big(\frac{1}{\mathbf 1^T C^{-1}\mathbf 1}\big)\cdot C^{-1}\mathbf 1$